# Volatilidade EWMA em um data.frame

Tags: r, data.frame

Tenho um data.frame `base_retorno_diario`, de 3560 observações em 110 ações (retornos diários), quero criar outro data.frame a partir desse com a Volatilidade ewma com `decay_factor = 0.97`

Exemplo do data.frame

```r
  Data       IBOV         ABEV3       AEDU3   ALLL3 BBAS3        BBDC3        BBDC4
1 2000-01-04 -0.063756245 0.00000000  0       0     -0.029935852 -0.080866107 -0.071453347
2 2000-01-05 0.024865308  -0.03762663 0       0     -0.008082292 0.043269231 0.060889055
3 2000-01-06 -0.008510238 -0.03157895 0       0      0.014074074 0.014285714 0.008098592
4 2000-01-07 0.012557359  -0.02484472 0       0     -0.022644266 0.017719219 0.000000000
5 2000-01-10 0.043716564  0.00000000  0       0     0.050074738 0.005357143 0.006985679
6 2000-01-11 -0.026401514 -0.02388535 0       0    -0.008540925 -0.059058615 -0.046479362
```

A primeira linha eu criei com o seguinte código (`n_row` e `n_col` são o número de linhas e colunas em `base_retorno_diario`)

```r
EWMA_VARIANCE = as.data.frame(base_retorno_diario[1,2:n_col]^2)
```

em seguida eu criei o seguinte loop

```r
i = 2
DECAY_FACTOR = 0.97
while(i<=n_row){EWMA_VARIANCE = rbind(EWMA_VARIANCE,EWMA_VARIANCE[(i-1),1:(n_col-1)]*DECAY_FACTOR +(1-DECAY_FACTOR)*base_retorno_diario[i,2:n_col]^2)
i=i+1
}
```

Ele funciona e cria o novo data.frame com a volatilidade de todas as ações no banco de dados, porem leva muito tempo, existe alguma maneira mais eficiente de codificar a mesma situação ?

Comment: Amigo, acredito que você possa melhorar MUITO a velocidade de execução se você utilizar matriz ao invés de dataframe ou datatable. Eu tive um problema semelhante aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/215414/somar-linha-a-linha-em-um-data-table-em-r

Há uma boa diferença na forma com que os dados estão alocados em um dataframe e em uma matriz. Quando se percorre por um for ou while, a forma como os dados são alocados impacta muito no tempo de execução.

Answer (score 2):

Segue o código com a resposta

A segunda função `variance.ewma` recebe uma matriz com os retornos das ações e o valor do fator de decaimento do EWMA, para cada coluna da matriz ela chama a função `ewma.func` e repassa o fator de decaimento aplicando o formula ewma para cada coluna, ao terminar de aplicar a formula em cada coluna ela retorna uma matriz com os resultados.

```r
ewma.func <- function(rets, lambda) {
rets[is.infinite(rets)] = 0
rets[is.nan(rets)] = 0
ewma.ant <- rets[1]^2
ewma <- vapply(rets, function(r) ewma.ant <<- ewma.ant *lambda + (r^2)*(1 - lambda), 0)
return(ewma)
}

variance.ewma <- function(bancodados,decayfactor){
EWMA = bancodados
for (i in 1:ncol(EWMA)){
EWMA[, i] = ewma.func(EWMA[, i], decayfactor) }
return(EWMA)}
```

Comment: não se esqueça de colocar a fonte para a resposta do MrFlick no SOEn. O método dele é bastante interessante.

Comment: É interessante checar o seguinte link para uma forma alternativa de se obter o mesmo resultado. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23791321/ewma-volatility-in-r-using-data-frames)