# Somar linha a linha em um data.table em R

Tags: r, data.rable-r

Existe algum método que se possa somar linha a linha em um data.table no R sem que necessite usar um 'for', de modo que o valor da próxima linha em uma coluna, seja o valor da linha anterior somado com um valor diferente a cada linha?

Tentando resolver um exercício de urnas em R, me deparei com o seguinte problema: tenho um data.table com uma coluna com o primeiro valor igual a 50 e o restante 0 (10^6 linhas), e a outra coluna contem -1 ou 1, correspondendo somar ou subtrair 1 desse número inicial. Porém, após somar ou subtrair, não pode ficar menor que zero ou maior que 100.

```
# Valores iniciais:
N <- 100             # Número total de bolas
nRetiradas <- 1e6   # Número de inteirações (retiradas) do problema
q <- 0.35            # Probabilidade de transferência para urna com n <= N/2
p <- 1.0 - q           # Probabilidade de transferência para urna com n > N/2

# A tabela urnas[] armazena o número de bolas em cada passo em cada retirada
urnas <- data.table(A <- rep(0, nRetiradas), B <- rep(0, nRetiradas))
setnames(urnas, names(urnas), c("A", "B"))
rm(A, B)

# Condição inicial das urnas A e B:
urnas$A[[1]] <- N/2
urnas$B[[1]] <- N/2

# Escolha aleatória: considero que 1 represente uma bola retirada de uma urna
# com n > N/2, e -1 para uma urna com n <= N/2. Gero uma sequência inicial 
# para uma das urnas e multiplico esta por -1 para a outra urna
retiradas_A <- ifelse(runif(nRetiradas)<q,-1,1)
retiradas_B <- (-1)*retiradas_A

foreach(i=2:nRetiradas) %do% {
  if(min(urnas$A[[i-1]] + retiradas_A[i], urnas$B[[i-1]] + 
         retiradas_B[i]) >= 0){
    urnas$A[[i]] <- urnas$A[[i-1]] + retiradas_A[i]
    urnas$B[[i]] <- urnas$B[[i-1]] + retiradas_B[i]    

  } else {
    urnas$A[[i]] <- urnas$A[[i-1]] + retiradas_B[i]
    urnas$B[[i]] <- urnas$B[[i-1]] + retiradas_A[i]   
  }
}
```

Da forma que implementei, cada linha do data.table dependerá da linha anterior e, por isso, só consegui resolver utilizando um for bem demorado. Mas para percorrer 10^6 linhas do data.table está demorando horrores. Há alguma solução mais eficiente? (mesmo que envolva modificar totalmente minha abordagem)

Comment: Deixa eu entender melhor:
Vc tem um data frame com duas colunas (urna_a e urna_b) onde cada linha corresponde ao estado (número de bolas) de cada repetição do seguinte experimento:

jogo uma moeda e transfiro uma bola da urna_a para a urna_b se for cara (com probabilidade p de ser cara).

O que deve acontecer se a quantidade de bolas na urna estourar? Eu paro a simulação?

Comment: Se a quantidade de bolas chegar à 0 em uma urna, eu removo da outra. E se chegar a 100, eu removo ao invés de adicionar. 
Não foi especificado no enunciado, mas adotei esta solução ou também ignorar até que se encontre uma remoção (no caso da urna estiver cheia).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consegui otimizar MUITO a execução utilizando **matrizes** ao invés de **data.table** (não havia nada no meu programa que justificasse a necessidade de um data.table).

Segue o código com solução que encontrei:

```
# Valores iniciais:
N <- 100             # Número total de bolas
nRetiradas <- 1e6   # Número de inteirações (retiradas) do problema
nDescarte <- 1e4    # Número de descartes no início da sequência
q <- 0.35            # Probabilidade de transferência para urna com n <= N/2
p <- 1.0 - q           # Probabilidade de transferência para urna com n > N/2

# A tabela urnas[] armazena o número de bolas em cada passo em cada retirada
urnas <- matrix(data = NA, nrow = nRetiradas, ncol = 2)

# Condição inicial das urnas A e B:
urnas[1,1] <- N/2
urnas[1,2] <- N/2

# Escolha aleatória: considero que 1 represente uma bola retirada de uma urna
# com n > N/2, e -1 para uma urna com n <= N/2. Gero uma sequência inicial 
# para uma das urnas e multiplico esta por -1 para a outra urna
retiradas_A <- ifelse(runif(nRetiradas)<q,-1,1)
retiradas_B <- (-1)*retiradas_A

tempoInicio <- Sys.time()

# foreach é um comando para realizar um laço 'for' utilizando 
# paralelismo entre os multiplos Cores disponíveis no hardware.
for(i in 2:nRetiradas) {
  if(min(urnas[i-1, 1] + retiradas_A[i], urnas[i-1,2] + 
         retiradas_B[i]) >= 0){
    urnas[i,1] <- urnas[i-1,1] + retiradas_A[i]
    urnas[i,2] <- urnas[i-1,2] + retiradas_B[i]    

  } else {
    urnas[i,1] <- urnas[i-1, 1]+ retiradas_B[i]
    urnas[i,2] <- urnas[i-1, 2] + retiradas_A[i]   
  }
}
```

Espero que em algum momento isso possa ajudar a quem se deparar com um problema semelhante!